# How to put a dot after three digits of a number

Tags: php

do you know how can i put a dot (.) after 3 digits of a number(starting from the end) in php?
example: the number 1254631 to be shown as 1.254.631??

Answer (score 45, accepted):

if you want to pretty print a number, [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is nice

```
echo number_format(1254631 , 0, ',', '.');  // prints 1.254.631
```

the last argument is the thousands separator (dot in your case)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/number_format).

Answer (score 1):

```
$printThisNumber = number_format($getThisNumber, 2, '.', ',');
```